# Fast Ax = b solver

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have got problem finding x with this equation $Ax = b$
where my matrix

$A=\mu.\Phi^T\Phi+\lambda.I$  where $\Phi$ is $m$ x $n$ Gaussian random matrix. 
$x,b$ is vector $n$ x $1$

where I already known all $\Phi, \mu, \lambda$, and they donot change. m = 102, n = 1024.

Loop 100 times

```
   find x st. Ax = b
   Change b
```

end

How can i make it fast? I haveben try in Matlab with 
[L U] = lu(A), A1 = Pinv(A), x = b\A

but they still very slow and Pinv(A) seems to be the best
Is there any way to speed it up?

---

Since I already know about A, i simply pre-calculate $A^{-1}$, and it turns back into Matrix multiplication. That why using Pinv(A) gives me the best performance. 
But I'm not sure is there any faster solution.

Comment: I don't know matlab, but your best bet will be to Cholesky-decompose the matrix. You only need to do this once for all b.

Comment: It doesnt work for mycase, it even takes longer time than if I take C = A^-1, and x = C.b. @@

Comment: That makes no sense. $C$ is positive-definite, Cholesky decomposition is pretty much the fastest direct solver available to you -- certainly *much* faster than Gaussian elimination, or whatever you are using to compute $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\mu, \lambda > 0$ you have a positive-definite matrix, and your fastest option will be to first solve for the Cholesky factors of $A$:
$$A = LL^T$$
with $L$ lower-triangular.  (If there is a risk that $A$ is poorly-conditioned, e.g. if $\lambda$ is very small, you should do an $LDL^T$ decomposition instead.)

You can then solve all of your linear systems
$$LL^Tx_i = b_i$$
using trivial back- and forward-subsitution.

If you have very few different $b_i$, you might want to look at iterative solvers, like the method of conjugate gradients; if the number of $b_i$ is large, though, a decomposition is your best bet.